# Need advices on android smart tv remote navigation

Tags: android, smart-tv

I'm porting over an android mobile app into an smart tv app (android based). There are some navigation problems by using the remote controller. I think that's because I don't need to take care of focus issue most of the time in the mobile app. Is there any good tutorials or articles about porting over the android mobile app into android smart tv, especially regarding with remote navigation part? Thanks

Comment: can u explain what part of your app need to be focused ?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a tour at Android TV official design guide pages at http://developer.android.com/design/tv/index.html

And especially you should pay attention to the UI design section http://developer.android.com/design/tv/patterns.html

There is also a session on the topic of "Create Quality Apps for TV" at 
http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tv.html

Comment: But these are not related to the navigation (focus issue). I found it's quite difficult.